# Meaning of "jemandem im Kopf herumspuken"?

Tags: meaning

I can't find translation for the phrase "jemandem im Kopf herumspuken".

What does it mean?

Comment: Since the title has "spuken" I assume that "spucken" in the text is a typo - but because it is not absolutely clear, I did not correct this one in my edit.

Comment: It is a very common expression, and every dictionary above median quality should have it. Where did you look?

Answer (score 4):

This might be roughly translated to

> haunt someone's mind

Answer (score 1):

Herumspuken:

*im Kopf:*

If I feel the presence of some thoughts/ a person that I might/ want/ should/ ... think about. It can be that I have only fragments of a thought and that I could take my time to think about it which it would no longer let them be unprecise.

If I refuse to think about it, it might be connected to fear what `spuken` is regarding ghosts. If I consider thinking about it, it might be connected to an upcoming idea.

There is also *other herumspuken*:

When people claim to feel the presence of dead (and famous) people at a location.

see [DWDS (for details)](https://www.dwds.de/wb/herumspuken)